# Sylius Product associations returns error for Sylius 1.10

Tags: sylius

I have tried using the latest beta versions of Sylius 1.10.0.ALPHA.1/1.10.0.BETA.1 (because I want to get Sylius running on PHP 8) and I get the same error when associating products from the backoffice "Unable to generate a URL for the named route "sylius_admin_api_product_option_show" as such route does not exist" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Joj8m.png)

on the version 1.9 of Sylius I dont get this error.
ps: when runing bin/console debug:router the route is there.
can someone help me with this. thank you.

Comment: This error comes from the removal of Admin API in v1.10.
There's an old issue related to it: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/9966.
In the meantime, you can override the serialization config for `Sylius\Component\Product\Model\ProductOption` and remove the relation.

Comment: I have trouble overriding ProductOption serialization config :/ I've updated serilizer config under /config/packages with this:
`metadata:
        directories:
            product-option:
                namespace_prefix: "App\\Entity"
                path: "%kernel.project_dir%/config/serializer"`

and Product.ProductOption.yml under config/serializer :

`App\Entity\Product\ProductOption:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
            type: integer
            xml_attribute: true
            groups: [Default, Detailed]`